# I would like to know on how to convert Oracle triggers into SQL Server triggers

Tags: sql-server, oracle

As I understand, SQL SERVER Triggers does not support FOR EACH ROW. Also I am aware that you have to use inserted tables and deleted tables. Other than that, I have no clue how to write SQL Server triggers. They look so different. Can some help please?

Below is the code for Oracle Triggers

```
create or replace TRIGGER Ten_Percent_Discount   
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Bookings  
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE CURSOR C_Passengers IS 
SELECT StatusName
FROM   Passengers
WHERE  PassengerNumber = :NEW.Passengers_PassengerNumber;
l_status_name Passengers.StatusName%TYPE;
BEGIN 
OPEN  C_Passengers;
FETCH C_Passengers INTO l_status_name;
CLOSE C_Passengers;
```

Below is what I have written so far. I know I am using the inserted tables wrong

```
IF l_status_name = 'Regular' 
THEN 
 :New.TotalCost := 0.90 * :New.TotalCost;
END IF;
END;

create TRIGGER Ten_Percent_Discount  
ON Customer
FOR INSERT ,UPDATE  
AS 
DECLARE  C_Passengers CURSOR FOR
SELECT StatusLevel
FROM   Customer
WHERE  CustomerID = inserted.CustomerID
```

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Table structure for customer

[image: Table structure for Customer]

Table structure for Order

[image: Table structure for Order]

Comment: May I know why you are writing sql server trigger on "customer" table when oracle trigger was on booking table?

Comment: @JayeshPrakash yes because they are different tables but the trigger works on the same logic.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind posting the table structure and your exact requirement with trigger for insert and delete cases in your question?

Comment: @JayeshPrakash Do you just want a screen print of how my table looks like? A screenprint?  The trigger requirement is if the the customer has a status of Standard, then I want the trigger to fire which will give a discount of 10 % of the Total Price in the orders table

Comment: Screenshot would work too, also what should trigger do in case of delete?

Comment: @JayeshPrakash It should not do anything in case of Delete. I have added the screenprints of the table structure. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below answer is only for reference purpose that you can use to build gradually towards final solution:

```
create table dbo.customer
(
customerid varchar(10),
firstname nvarchar(50),
statuslevel varchar(50)
)
go
create table dbo.customerorder
(
orderid varchar(10),
totalprice numeric(5,2),
productid varchar(10),
customerid varchar(10)
)
go
go
create trigger dbo.tr_customer on dbo.customer for insert,update
as
begin
    update co
    set co.totalprice = .9*co.totalprice
    from dbo.customerorder co
    inner join inserted i
    on co.customerid = i.customerid
    where i.statuslevel = 'Standard' 
end
go

--test for above code
insert into dbo.customer values (1,'jayesh','')
insert into dbo.customerorder values (1,500.25,1,1)
insert into dbo.customerorder values (1,600.25,2,1)
select * from dbo.customer
select * from dbo.customerorder

update dbo.customer set statuslevel = 'Standard' where customerid = 1

select * from dbo.customer
select * from dbo.customerorder
```

But what I am pretty sure is that when customer is created for the first time, there will not be any orders to apply discounts on, so you will certainly need UPDATE Trigger as well.

Comment: Do I just have to add another if statement if I was to give a 5 per cent discount if the customer was regular?

Comment: you can use CASE statement in the trigger update. Something like "set co.totalprice = CASE i.statuslevel when 'Standard' then .9 when 'Regular' then .5 else 1 end * co.totalprice". Also in this case do not forget to remove the where clause. Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: Ahh cheers mate!! I was stuck on  this for a while. Thank you so much for helping on the right path. It is much appreciated. @jayesh

Answer (score 1):

Hello another approach can be in this way:

```
CREATE  TABLE Passengers (
    PassengerNumber INT PRIMARY KEY,
    StatusName NVARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO Passengers (PassengerNumber, StatusName)
VALUES 
    (1, 'Regular'),
    (2, 'Regular'),
    (3, 'Frequent'),
    (4, 'Regular');


CREATE TABLE Bookings (
    BookingID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Passengers_PassengerNumber INT,
    TotalCost DECIMAL(10, 2),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PassengerNumber FOREIGN KEY (Passengers_PassengerNumber) REFERENCES Passengers(PassengerNumber)
);

INSERT INTO Bookings (BookingID, Passengers_PassengerNumber, TotalCost)
VALUES
    (101, 1, 100.00),
    (102, 2, 150.00),
    (103, 3, 200.00),
    (104, 4, 120.00);

CREATE or alter TRIGGER Ten_Percent_Discount
ON Bookings
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @l_status_name NVARCHAR(50);

    SELECT @l_status_name = P.StatusName
    FROM Passengers P
    WHERE P.PassengerNumber = (SELECT Passengers_PassengerNumber FROM inserted);

    IF @l_status_name = 'Regular'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Bookings
        SET TotalCost = 0.9 * TotalCost
        WHERE BookingID = (SELECT BookingID FROM inserted);
    END
END;
```

Hope it helps.